# Moto G 2014 XT1068 is bricked. Keeps looping and won't boot. What to do?

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, motorola-moto-g, bootloader

Ok so here's a couple things about my phone:
Its bootloader is unlocked, it is rooted, and it has a custom recovery (TWRP).

The problem is, my phone got stuck in the "WARNING, BOOTLOADER IS UNLOCKED" screen. I was using it normally, when Chrome froze then the phone turned off. It won't do anything else, it just keeps looping: it shows the warning, then the screen goes blank. When I try going into recovery mode, it just shows the TEAMWIN splash screen and won't do anything else, even though I tried every possible button combination I could find on the internet (volume up, down, power, 15 secs, 1 minute, etc).

It gets worse. When I'm on fastboot mode, I can plug the phone on my PC via USB but it won't be recognized. It appears on the device manager as "fastboot titan s" but the phone itself just keeps saying "Connect USB data cable" as if it's not connected.

It won't be recognized by RDSLite nor mfastboot applications, even though it shows up on device manager.

What can I do?